# Xcode 4 variable summaries in debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode4

In Xcode 3, when viewing variables with the debugger, there was a "Summary" column, shown in [this image](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/art/debugger.jpg). You could edit what appeared there, so you could preview all kinds of data types. In Xcode 4, I can't find similar functionality. I've found I can right-click the variables and choose "Edit Summary Format...", but though I can edit it like in Xcode 3, the actual result doesn't seem to show up anywhere! This demonstrates my problem:

[image: Xcode 4 variable view]

As you can see, there's no summary column. How can I actually see the result of the summary in Xcode 4?

Comment: There is a Summary column. The 20 objects next to the values variable at the top of the screenshot is the summary. As a test, select a variable with a blank summary, choose Edit Summary Format, and enter the word Test as the format string. The word Test should appear next to the variable as the summary. If the word Test appears, the problem is most likely in your summary format string. If the word doesn't appear, there's something wrong with Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh, I was having lots of issues with Xcode, so I just ended up doing a clean install. It seems to have fixed the issues. Oh well.